# Change Joomla 3 & 4 page title and site name separator from '-' to '|'

Tags: joomla3.0

how would i change the joomla page title and site name separator from - to |. I know which file generates the  file. It's located at C:\xampp\htdocs\Yoursitename\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php

```
$buffer .= $tab . '<title>' . htmlspecialchars($document->getTitle(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '</title>' . $lnEnd;
```

I just can't figure out where the getTitle function is coming from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It uses a language constant `JPAGETITLE` which in english is set to `%1$s - %2$s`

You can use the language override manager in your Joomla backend to change that.

The title itself is usually set in the view you look at. There `JDocument->setTitle()` is used. Like for example here for com_content, article view: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php#L256